Gaps in summed time-series data with multiple targets
I have continuous time-series data in prometheus that comes from two different target VMs.
When I use a 'sum by(topic)' it's either missing or got gaps in the series.
eg:
sum by(topic) (kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag{application="abc123", topic="xyz"}  )

If I sum with just 1 target VM, everything is working fine (e.g. adding 'instance=abc123' to the query). It's when we try to sum up across both services when there are gaps.
Any thoughts?

Looks like the issue is some time-series had NaN in them. When Prometheus sum's a value with an NaN, it gives an NaN.
Answer is to add a >0 to the query, so:
sum by(topic) (kafka_consumer_fetch_manager_records_lag{application="abc123", topic="xyz"} >0 )

Found the answer in another post:

prometheus sum one NaN value result into NaN. How to avoid it?


Wow, very interesting problem. You should probably also look into why your exporter gives out NaN for lag value; don't think this is normal behaviour.
